# What are the numbers in the file names in next bundle analyzer?

Tags: webpack, next.js, webpack-bundle-analyzer

Just started using next bundle analyzer. I cannot understand what these random numbers are, which are being given to specific pages of the Next app.

[image]

For eg: `1883.js`. What is 1883?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're the different sizes for that specific webpack chunk.

From the [`webpack-bundle-analyzer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer#size-definitions) documentation (used internally by `next-bundle-analyzer`):

> `webpack-bundle-analyzer` reports three values for sizes. `defaultSizes` can be used to control which of these is shown by default. The
> different reported sizes are:
>
> - **`stat`** This is the "input" size of your files, before any
>   transformations like minification.
>   It is called "stat size" because it's obtained from Webpack's [stats object](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/).
> - **`parsed`** This is the "output" size of your files. If you're using a
>   Webpack plugin such as Uglify, then this value will reflect the
>   minified size of your code.
> - **`gzip`** This is the size of running the parsed bundles/modules through
>   gzip compression.

Comment: i think i was not clear. I do not mean the size, but the number assigned to the js script

Comment: Oh, those are the chunk names generated by webpack.